# How can I improve effect of Clustering of MNIST?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

Limit us with Clustering technology, like `FindClusters`, `ClusteringComponents`,`ClusterClassify`,`FeatureExtraction`,`DimensionReducion`.

```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
trainingData=ResourceData[resource,"TrainingData"];
testData=ResourceData[resource,"TestData"];
trainingSet=RandomSample[trainingData,5000];
testSet=RandomSample[testData,1000];
methods = {"KMeans", "Agglomerate", "KMedoids", "Spectral"};
Do[clusters[i]=FindClusters[dTrain,10,Method->i,DistanceFunction->CosineDistance,PerformanceGoal->"Quality"];
length=Length/@clusters[i];
Print@length,{i,methods}]
```

---Basic effect

```
fe=DimensionReduction[trainingSet[[All,1]],Method->"TSNE"];
dTrainDR=Thread[fe[trainingSet[[All,1]]]->trainingSet[[All,2]]];
Do[c[i]=ClusterClassify[dTrainDR[[All,1]],10,Method->i,PerformanceGoal->"Quality"],{i,methods}]
asso=GroupBy[dTrainDR,Last->First];
KeySort[ReverseSort@Counts[c[methods[[1]]]@#]&/@asso]//Normal//Column
0-><|2->446,10->15,4->3,7->1|>
1-><|6->422,8->130,1->12,5->3,4->1|>
2-><|4->408,6->69,8->16,1->8,2->8,5->6,10->5,9->2,3->1|>
3-><|7->405,8->32,5->23,1->5,10->5,2->4,4->3,6->3,9->2,3->1|>
4-><|3->224,1->153,5->72,9->47,6->14,10->2,8->1|>
5-><|7->192,8->149,5->108,10->22,3->6,2->3,1->2,6->2|>
6-><|10->483,8->3,4->2,5->2,3->1,6->1,2->1,7->1|>
7-><|9->259,1->178,5->37,6->17,3->15,4->2,10->1|>
8-><|8->222,5->138,7->66,10->12,1->10,6->8,3->6,2->5,4->1|>
9-><|3->162,1->146,9->124,5->51,7->4,6->2,8->2,2->2|>
```

and we see, 4 and 9 is similar, 5 and 3 is similar, the question is not limit to Hard Clustering, also Soft Clustering, we can raise up some evaluation, topK accuracy like some evaluating indicators in Classify.

I'll update my experiments and notebook here or some places, glad to know more about this topic.[my experiment notebook](https://github.com/HyperGroups/MathematicaMachineLearning/tree/master/MNIST/Clustering@MNIST.nb)

For example, more accuracy, what feature, what distance, what cluster method, what dimension reduce function  gives better result?

Comment: I don't follow. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @MarcoB  For example, what feature, what distance, what cluster method, what dimension reduce function gives better result?

Comment: Maybe TSNE will help.